# How to prevent touch on all elements except one using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a popover and I want to prevent scrolling in the background when it is open. Doing this for desktop using CSS is easy:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

IOS however doesn't respect this rule and still allows the background to be scrolled when the user is actually scrolling the popover.

Disabling touch on the wrapper element which contains everything on the page except the the popover doesn't work:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('touchstart touchmove touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

However disabling touch everywhere does work:

```
$('*').bind('touchstart touchmove touchend', false);
```

How can I just disable it everywhere except the popover element?

### UPDATE

Popover CSS:

```
.popover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create your popover as a single full page div that acts to 'block' events from reaching the body. Place the popover in front of this div.

You can block the event using JS as you have, or with `element {point-events:none}` and 'undo' it with `element {pointer-events:auto}`

Comment: I believe my popover already blocks everything on the page, please see my updated answer for my popover's CSS.